# Multiple block operations called via addObserver:selector:name:object:

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue, nsnotificationcenter

I have an app where an user action attempts to connect to an online resource. The connection process is done by a thirdPartySDK, and success or failure is signaled back asynchronously. This is handled by the appDelegate which I configured to post a notification either way. (ie Dropbox style).

Below, assuming failure, the ***UIAlertView*** gets called as many times as the operation is executed. That is, if I repeatedly test the connection and it fails, the first time the block is called once, the second time the block is called two times, 3rd time 3 calls, etc. It is as-if the block operation is not canceled or removed from the queue.

```
if (!opQ) {
    opQ = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
}

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:LINK_NOTIFICATION_FAILURE object:nil queue:opQ usingBlock:^(NSNotification *aNotification) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
     ^{
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network_Account_Not_Linked" message:@"Your_attempt_to_link_your_account_ended_unsuccessfully" 
          delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

     });

}];
```

The problem appears to be with ***addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:*** . I tested with ***addObserver:selector:name:object:*** which works fine (one selector execution per notification). Using the block is more convenient, makes the code more readable and give access to local variables, hence my motivation.

I tried ***[opQ cancelAllOperations]*** in the NSBlockOperation thread and the dispatch_async (***opQ*** is at that point is "out of scope" according to the debugger). Also, used ***[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]*** with similar failed results. In addition, I also tried starting with a fresh opQ for prior to registering for the the notification... nada.

Why are the multiple calls happening? Is there a better approach using blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple Documentation for the method you're using says:

> To unregister observations, you pass the object returned by this method to removeObserver:. You must invoke removeObserver: or removeObserver:name:object: before any object specified by addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: is deallocated.

In other words, you can't just simply pass `self` when removing observer.

Try:

```
__block id observer = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:LINK_NOTIFICATION_FAILURE object:nil queue:opQ usingBlock:^(NSNotification *aNotification) {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
 ^{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network_Account_Not_Linked" message:@"Your_attempt_to_link_your_account_ended_unsuccessfully" 
      delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:observer];

 });
}];
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried it but did not work. Received an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the id observer = ... statement 2nd time. I simplified the code eliminating the opQ and using [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]. Same crash. Eliminated GCD... same crash.

Comment: OK, a little more digging reveals this issue is a duplicate of 8477629. Answer is to add `__block id observer = ...`

Comment: I was going to suggest using `__block id ...` just before your comment...ha...I'll update the answer...